# XSLT Rules that brake and symbols that change meaning

Tags: xslt

These are just some observations born out of frustration while learning XSLT.

**Meaning of the symbols changes depending on position and context**

Following three lines show the usage of '/' character and in each line that character symbolizes something COMPLETELY different.
    In first line represents root node, in second child-parent relationship and in third descendants of people element.
    In other words the meaning of the same character has been overridden three times and it completely changes meaning depending on the position and the surrounding context.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:template match="people/person">
<xsl:template match="people//name">
```

**Rules brake when combined**

In the following expression '/' means root node.

`<xsl:template match="/">`.

In the following expression '/' means that person is child of people.

`<xsl:template match="people/person">`.

Now if you try to combine these two rules to reference people which should be child of the root node you write `<xsl:template match="//people">` and get the expected result but only by accident.

That is because '//' has completely new meaning that has nothing to do with root node or child parent relationship.
    It means all descendants and in this context it refers to all descendant of the root node and not just the people child.

**It makes me wonder**

With all these problems plaguing XSLT it makes me wonder who were the people that created it, what exactly did they try to achieve, what were their guidelines and who are indented users.
    I am sure that these people are extremely smart since XSLT is extremely complicated.
    But I wonder if they were creating this monster only for them selves either deliberately making it so unnecessary complex and confusing in order to erect artificial barrier against everybody else or if they simply couldn't care less about others that might want to use it as long as the thing seems usable to them.

Comment: "*who were the people that created it, what exactly did they try to achieve, what were their guidelines and who are indented users.*" These questions are off-topic for SO.

Comment: OH I think I understand now. Referencing elements uses the same syntax as referencing directories on a UNIX system . I know it seema obvious but I only realised that today. I wonder why non of the tutorals mentiones that paralel. Instead of confronting user with a half a screeb big table with allof those alian symbol single line making paralel with directories would be 100 times more worth.